# Akka, DDD and hierarchy of actors as aggregates

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, akka

I know Akka and the actor model works well in a DDD approach. However, I do have one question about the hierarchy.

Imagine that I have a system where we can send messages to users. I may have one `UserActor` and a `MessageActor`.

```
              +-----------+    +--------------+
(CreateUser)->| UserActor |    | MessageActor |<-(CreateMessage) 
              |-----------|    |--------------|
              | + id      |    | + id         |
              +-----------+    | + userId     |
                               +--------------+

# The hierarchy is "flat":
 /system
    /user
    /message
```

At some time, we may want to disable an user, and we do not want this user to accept any new messages.

It seems to be useful to have the `UserActor` receiving the `CreateMessage` and `Disable` commands. So that a disabled user can reject new messages without having to maintain that state somewhere else.

```
                 +------------+      +--------------+
   (CreateUser)->| UserActor  |      | MessageActor | 
                 |------------|      |--------------|
                 | + id       |   /->| + id         |
(CreateMessage)->| + messages |--/   +--------------+
                 +------------+                       


# The hierarchy is a true hierarchy:
/system
   /user
       /message
```

Is that a common usage or is it better to limit the number of child actors and use other mechanism to maintain the constraints ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking that the `UserActor` should be aggregate root?

Comment: Yes. I guess it should be, and the message en entity. However, my question is more about the architecture of those actors. Should I keep both on the same level of the hierarchy or use a parent-child relation from the user to the message(s) ?

Comment: If you choose the `UserActor` to be the aggregate root then only that actor should be persistent actor to preserve state. If your `UserActor` is a peer of `MessageActor` then both should be persistent BUT different supervision strategy can be defined for them. Based on the shared information I would go with the parent-child relationship.

Comment: Thanks. But why can't we persist the `MessageActor` too ? I could have `CreateMessage`->`UserActor` that spawn a persistent `MessageActor` and keep only the persistence-id of that message inside the `UserActor`.

Comment: Well you can. I haven't used Akka for awhile but if my memory servers well it is enough to store state in the aggregate root and propagate that to the children actors.

Answer (score 0):

It can sometimes be useful to model the constituent entities of an aggregate as child actors of some root: a lot of the transactional guarantees needed for an aggregate can be provided by cluster sharding (or a map of ids to `ActorRef`s in the non-cluster case), but since you're modeling the entities as multiple actors, the actor-model's one-at-a-time message processing won't apply.  The way around that limitation is to use stashing in the root actor for the aggregate: while it's deferring processing to its children, if it stashes incoming commands the whole constellation of actors will still present as one to the outside world.

Because Akka Typed (which is generally recommended) makes it a little clunky (especially in Scala) to have a persistent actor also have children, when doing this, I tend to have a child dedicated for managing the root's persistence (this child can be a very thin wrapper over the persistence API, e.g. you might have a command like `PersistEvents` which will reply on success with the updated state).

This is especially useful in situations where you can have arbitrarily many entities within an aggregate's state, but you don't want the state which has to be loaded into memory to always entail all of them (e.g. loading what you need on demand).  Aggregates representing long-lived things where you reserve the right to look back over the history are one use-case.

So in this approach your root actor is generally going to:

- receive a command
- figure out which children (if any) need to be spawned
- direct internal commands to those children
- wait for replies, stashing incoming commands until there's a reply

In essence, this is a saga, though if the interactions with the children are effectively idempotent you can dispense with making the saga itself persistent.